# How would one go about printing out a certain pattern to the console, given a random size?

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment for my computer science class in school, in which we have to print out the following pattern, of random size (width, height).

```
..............................X..............................
..................................X..........................
.......................................X.....................
...........................................X.................
...............................................X.............
...................................................X.........
......................................................X......
........................................................X....
..........................................................X..
...........................................................X.
............................................................X
...........................................................X.
..........................................................X..
........................................................X....
......................................................X......
...................................................X.........
...............................................X.............
...........................................X.................
.......................................X.....................
..................................X..........................
..............................X..............................
..........................X..................................
.....................X.......................................
.................X...........................................
.............X...............................................
.........X...................................................
......X......................................................
....X........................................................
..X..........................................................
.X...........................................................
X............................................................
.X...........................................................
..X..........................................................
....X........................................................
......X......................................................
.........X...................................................
.............X...............................................
.................X...........................................
.....................X.......................................
..........................X..................................
..............................X..............................
```

I'm almost 100% certain that my way of going about it is wrong, considering most of it is hard coded. I've spent hours thinking of different ways to go about the problem. I tried finding a formula for the curve, but I cannot, for the life of me, find one that fits perfectly. Also, even if I did have a formula, I don't know how to go about implementing it while printing to the console. My code currently only prints a fixed size of the pattern.

My code:

```
String pattern = "X";
String background = ".";
for(int i = 31; i < 61; i += 0) {
    String output = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < 61; j++) {
        if(j == i) {
            output += pattern;
        } else {
            output += background;
        }
    }
    output = output.substring(2);
    System.out.println(output);
    if(i == 35) i += 5;
    else if(i > 30 && i < 52) i += 4;
    else if(i == 52) i += 3;
    else if(i >= 55 && i < 59) i += 2;
    else i++;
}
for(int i = 59; i >= 31; i += 0) {
    String output = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < 61; j++) {
        if(j == i) {
            output += pattern;
        } else {
            output += background;
        }
    }
    output = output.substring(2);
    System.out.println(output);
    if(i <= 59 && i >= 57) i -= 2;
    else if(i == 55) i -= 3;
    else if(i <= 52 && i > 40) i -= 4;
    else if(i == 40) i -= 5;
    else i -= 4;
}
for(int i = 27; i >= 0; i += 0) {
    if(i <= 1) break;
    String output = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < 61; j++) {
        if(j == i) {
            output += pattern;
        } else {
            output += background;
        }
    }
    output = output.substring(2);
    System.out.println(output);
    if(i == 31) i -= 4;
    else if(i == 27) i -= 5;
    else if(i == 10) i -= 3;
    else if(i <= 7 && i >= 5) i -= 2; 
    else if(i <= 5) i--;
    else i -= 4;
}
for(int i = 3; i <= 31; i += 0) {
    String output = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < 61; j++) {
        if(j == i) {
            output += pattern;
        } else {
            output += background;
        }
    }
    output = output.substring(2);
    System.out.println(output);
    if(i >= 3 && i <= 5) i += 2;
    else if(i == 7) i += 3;
    else if(i >= 10 && i <= 18) i += 4;
    else if(i == 22) i += 5;
    else i += 4;
}
```

Obviously, my way is inefficient and incorrect. I don't want the code typed out for me, but some pseudocode that points me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: *"of random size"* If random number is 5, should it print 5 times the whole pattern? Or just the first 5 lines of it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question to make that more clear. The width and height are two separate integers and they effect the length of each line and the number of lines printed respectively.

Comment: Still that doesn't answer my question, please post an example with the smallest case and one in the middle between that and the one you posted already

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be printing character by character through System.out.print and System.out.println using nested for loops for the x and the y axis, then replace the appropriate stars with X's.

Comment: Yes, that does seem a lot simpler, however I don’t know how to calculate the location of the X. My main problem is finding a formula or algorithm to get that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern you show reminds me of [sinusoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine).

Though my Sine Wave Printer doesn't 100% match with the original output, it can give you an idea where to start. You can try rotating and joining several [parabolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) or graphs of other math functions that come to your mind, or play with the example below to get what you need.

### Example

The following code snippet prints 'X' relying on `Math.sin` function (note that it uses angle in radians as argument):

```
// Configurations
Integer DEFAULT_ROW_LEN = 61;
Integer NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 1000;
char DEFAULT_ROW_CONTENT = '.';
Double SPEED = 2.8;

// Preparing row of dots
StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_ROW_LEN; i++) {
    row.append(DEFAULT_ROW_CONTENT);
}

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i += SPEED) {

    // Loop progress
    double relativeProgress = i / DEFAULT_ROW_LEN.doubleValue();

    // In projection on a circle
    double circleProgress  = relativeProgress * Math.PI * 2;

    // Remember that sin goes from -1 to +1, but we need to fit the curve within 0 to +1
    double consoleProgress  = (Math.sin(circleProgress) + 1) / 2;

    // Exact index in the row to highlight
    int  exactPosition = (int) (consoleProgress * DEFAULT_ROW_LEN);
    row.setCharAt(exactPosition, 'X');

    // Print current progress and restore defaults
    System.out.println(row);
    row.setCharAt(exactPosition, DEFAULT_ROW_CONTENT);
}
```

### Output

```
..............................X..............................
....................................X........................
..........................................X..................
................................................X............
....................................................X........
........................................................X....
...........................................................X.
............................................................X
............................................................X
...........................................................X.
.........................................................X...
.....................................................X.......
.................................................X...........
............................................X................
......................................X......................
................................X............................
.........................X...................................
...................X.........................................
..............X..............................................
.........X...................................................
.....X.......................................................
..X..........................................................
X............................................................
X............................................................
X............................................................
..X..........................................................
......X......................................................
..........X..................................................
...............X.............................................
.....................X.......................................
...........................X.................................
.................................X...........................
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement this and keep you updated on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as requested, not gonna mouth feed you with code but rather a direction towards your coding pattern

The bottom line is to use methods, they are amazing features and helps you simplify your problem (and your thinking pattern).

One method, I particularly find useful is to print a line `printLine(int length,int location,char c){...}`
 where length is the length of the line, location is where the char c should be printed.

another method you should consider is to calculate X location: `getLocation(int length,int prev)` : which uses the previous location and calculate the next one .

now all you need to do is loop through the number of lines, calculate next location and print the line.

I hope this helps you understand the problem better.

Comment: I don't think this should be considered a full solution, it's a suggestion if anything.  If you don't want to mouth feed use psudocode or examples for a better, more specific explanation.

Comment: The main problem for me isn’t printing the line itself, but finding the right position to put the X. I don’t have any algorithm or formula to find it and I think I’ll need one to print different sizes of the pattern.

Comment: @jthort ur right its not a solution, but rather a direction. I know its not a good answer for stackoverflow, but it couldn't have been as a comment as its too long.

Comment: @IshawnGullapalli if you break down the problem, you can easily focus on a particular problem. Just think about the suggested getLocation method and its param. the param suggested probably is not enough. My whole point is for you to break down the problem.